# How to uncheck a layer in LayerSwitcher on map load?

Tags: openlayers-2

I have four layers in the LayerSwitcher. When the map is loaded all the layers are checked by default. I do not want to show all Layers as checked.How do I uncheck a layer when the map is loaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the layer's [setVisibility](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.setVisibility) function to turn them off before you add them to the map.

Answer (score 1):

You can get idea from the view page source code of [this](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/layerswitcher.html) example.

In given below example, I have added village layer which will be loaded unchecked default on map load. In that code, I have used *setVisibility()* function.

```
var village = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Village", "http://localhost:8090/geoserver/cite/wms",
        {
              LAYERS: 'cite:Village_Boundary_geo',
              STYLES: '',
              format: format,
              transparent: true
        },
        {
              singleTile: true,
              ratio: 1,
              isBaseLayer: false,
              yx : {'EPSG:4326' : true}
       }
     );

village.setVisibility(false);

map.addLayers([village]);
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if it contained an example of the situation of the problem listed in the question and possibly some content from the link you provided.